# How Do I Select a Compiler in Premake 5?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, premake

Since [MSVC has a compiler bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1590961) that has been blocking effective progress on my work, I would like to switch over to the Intel C++ Compiler.

I do not see an established way to do this in Premake.  The closest thing I can find is [this example](https://github.com/Robbbert/mameui/blob/master/scripts/toolchain.lua), which sets `premake.vstudio.toolset`.  I tried this myself, with no effect, so I assume this worked for a past version of Premake's rapidly changing API.  What is the current method (Premake 5)?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but looking at https://github.com/premake/premake-core/blob/master/src/tools/msc.lua and https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/toolset it feels like you could create a small module which adds a `premake.tools.intel` table, and then use the msc one as a base to implement it ? You can also check the `d` official module for a reference implementation, although it seems a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would select a compiler using the `toolset()` API:

```
toolset "clang"
```

There currently is no support for the Intel C++ compiler. You can [file a feature request](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/issues) (update: I see you've already done this) or, if you feel like tackling it yourself, you can create a new module to add the support yourself. Have a look at the existing toolset adapters in Premake's source code at `src/tools`.